# Why does iPhone 6 automatically scroll down web page content 64px on page refresh?

Tags: ios, iphone, scroll, page-refresh, iphone-6

On the iPhone 6 when I type in my site's domain in the address bar and hit enter/GO, everything loads fine and the page is displayed and scrolled all the way at the top (as expected). However, right afterwards, if I refresh the page by hitting the refresh button, whenever the page loads, it is automatically scrolled/offsetted 64px from the top (a scroll event is actually fired as well). This seems to be the same height as the address bar. Any ideas how to prevent this?